# Concatenate info from two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have the first name in column A and the last name in Column B and I need to combine them into just column A.  Also not sure if I need to check this in the code but some of the cells are empty with now names.  I have tried many things but they all want me to pull the two and enter them into a different or 3rd column.  But I need to put them into column A.

This is the code I have and it keeps giving me the merge error.

```
With Worksheet

    For Counter = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
        Range("BD2:BE1000").Merge Across:=True
    Next Counter

End With
```

Comment: Without any code this question will get closed pretty quickly.  You need to make an attempt, then post what you tried.  See [ask]

Comment: I have tried several possible solutions but they all give the error about the two cells containing data and won't let me concatenate the first and last name. I have added the basic code I have been using above.  I am probably missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use string concatenation here (assuming that lastrow (1000) and firstrow (2) have been set up properly in your sample code).

```
With Worksheet    
    For Counter = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
        .Range("BD" & counter).Value = .Range("BD" & counter).value & .Range("BE" & counter).value
    Next Counter    
End With
```

Comment: It looks like it should work but it errors out on the first.Value saying it is an invalid use of a property

Comment: Sorry I fat fingered the equal sign as a minus sign. Fixed. Please try again

Comment: If `with`is used, you should also use this in every `.Range`

Comment: @KekuSemau I missed that. I've editted to add that.

Answer (score 0):

**Concatenate (non-empty) names into one column**

- **`[1]`** In a first step you can assign your data range (object variable e.g. `rng`) to a variant 1-based 2-dim datafield array by a one liner `v = rng` or `v = rng.Value2`.
- **`[2]`** In a second step you loop through all array rows and check for non-empty names concatenating these findings in the array's first columns (overwriting the original single name part).
- **`[3]`** Resizing the receiving range to 1 column only (and the number of non-empty rows allows you to write the results back to sheet.

**Code example**

```
Option Explicit                                ' declaration head of your code module enforces declaration of variables/objects

Sub ConcatenateNames()
Dim v As Variant, rng As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")         ' <<~~ change to your sheet name

   ' [1] assign names to 2-dim datafield array v
     Set rng = .Range("BD2:BE1000")             ' set user defined range to memory
     v = rng.Value2                             ' get data
   ' [2] loop through data
     Dim i As Long, ii As Long
     For i = 1 To UBound(v)
       ' [2a] check for non empty names
         If Len(Trim(v(i, 1)) & Trim(v(i, 2))) > 0 Then
           ' [2b] concatenate first and last names in array v
             ii = ii + 1                         ' increment counter
             v(ii, 1) = v(i, 1) & " " & v(i, 2)
         End If
     Next i
   ' [3] write back to sheet and resize receiving range to ii rows and 1 column
     rng.Clear                                   ' clear original data
     rng.Resize(ii, 1) = v                       ' write names back to sheet

End With
End Sub
```

**Further hint**

Take care of the leading point **`.`** before *"Range"* referring to your worksheet object: `Set rng = .Range("BD2:BE1000")`